# How to stop taking a input on a condition in Python

Tags: python-3.x, input, user-input

I was trying to create a wed launching app. There I wanted to use a warning input function like this, but it will stop in a time.

```
print("Website will open in 30 seconds. To stop type 'no'.")
Ui=input ()  #ask input if the user wants to stop the command
Start=time.time()
if time.time()-Start==30: #wait for 30 seconds
    Ui.stop() #to stop asking input and go to the next line
#codes to open or not open the link
print("Link opened")
```

But maybe there is no stop function like `Ui.stop` or something like that. What should I do?

Comment: Can you please provide more details on what you are trying to achieve? The input() function allows user input. Ui.stop() makes no sense.

Comment: @bart I was trying to stop the input like it won't ask for any input